# Warning: mysqli_free_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Tags: php, mysqli

Why am I getting this error message:

> Warning: mysqli_free_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

My code is:

```
$statement = "INSERT INTO table1 (data1, data2) VALUES ('$variable1', '$variable2')";

if ($result = mysqli_query($conn,$statement)) {
echo "New record added successfully";
          } else {
    echo "Error adding records: " . $result . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

echo "Adding records finished. ";

mysqli_free_result($result);
```

Comment: 1. Why are you doing `mysqli_free_result` twice? 2. For what line of code you see this warning?

Comment: Oops, fixed that. I get the error message for this line: mysqli_free_result($result);

Comment: There're **TWO** such lines. Improve your code in a question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the duplicate code!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As stated in the [mysqli_query manual](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.query.php):

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

Your insert query will return true or false, but not an object. So, calling `mysqli_free_result` will not work here.

Comment: Use: if ( isset($result) && is_resource($result) ) { mysqli_free_result($result); }